# twitter like reply button using jquery and php get function?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter

i wanted to implemant the reply button so it takes a value through get function and put that in the update textbox just like twitter!! is thier a toturial or article, or you could guide me the right way i can do this!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution would be to build a link for reply, which has all the values it needs. `onClick` javascript comes to help, it reads the link variables and uses them for your textbox.

Like, if you have a link - `post.php?replyto=username&othervariable=value`, you use JavaScript (well, it can be jQuery or any other library too) to parse your URL, select `replyto` variable, and insert its value inside your textbox.

But there are many other solutions out there. If you want to achieve this with PHP, then - when the link is clicked, reload page with variable passed, and `$_GET` this value, then insert it in textbox again.

Comment: This is essentially what Twitter does. (+1)

Comment: thanks for the answer, i just dnt understand clearly, im so stupid!!